# Moving a button with ng-class

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

So I have this button which, when clicked upon, should move 480px to the right and change icon. I am using Angular JS and the changing of the icon works, but the button does not move.

This my is my HTML:

```
<div id="menuButton" ng-click="toggleMenu()">
    <div class="hamburgerMenuButton" ng-class="menu.shown ? 'menuOpen' : 'menuClosed'">

    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#menuButton {
    width:52px;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 10px;
    z-index: 1000;
    position: relative;
}

#menuButton:hover {
    background-color: #02CDED;
    border-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.hamburgerMenuButton {
    width: 32px;
    height: 30px;
}

.menuOpen {
    left: 480px;
    background-image: url('images/arrow.png');
} 

.menuClosed {
    background-image: url('images/hamburger.png');
}
```

When I look in the developers view in Chrome I can see that the class changes on the hamburgerMenuButton div, and the property left: 480px; is added, but it just does not move. The icon does change as expected.

Comment: That does not work at all. The icon dissappears completely, so even the menuClosed class does not get added which should happen on loading the page.

Comment: This has nothing to do with angular, your classes are being applied. I would look into the css itself, pretend angular isn't even there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `position:relative;`, or `position:inherit;`, to the `.hamburgerMenuButton`.

It's not moving because it has position set to `static`, per default. The `left` does not mean anything to the element.

Though you've set `position:relative;` on the parent `div`, it just so happens that [`position` is not an inherited property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/position);